# SSLHandshakeError when connecting to Google Analytics using Google APIs Client Library for Python

Tags: python, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to connect to Google Analytics using a Service Account, but I get the following error:

```
SSLHandshakeError at ...
[Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I have PyOpenSSL and PyCrypto installed and updated.

Here's the code I use to connect:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2

def initialize_service():
    f = open('path_to_key_file.p12', 'rb')

    key = f.read()
    f.close()    
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('XXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com', key, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly')
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    print 'This is printed'
    service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)
    print 'This is not printed'

    return service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem occurred because the system clock wasn't set to the current time.